# How to set the type of NSBatchDeleteResult of a NSBatchDeleteRequest?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have some core that performs a Batch delete request:

```
extension NSManagedObject: Clearable {
    /// Clears all objects of this type in coreData
    static func clearAll() {
        let context = AppDelegate.sharedInstance()?.coreDataHelper.objectContext()
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: String(describing:self))
        let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
        do {
            if let unwrappedContext = context {
                unwrappedContext.shouldDeleteInaccessibleFaults = true
                let result = try unwrappedContext.execute(batchDeleteRequest) as? NSBatchDeleteResult
                DLog("result \(result.debugDescription)")
                switch result!.resultType {
                case .resultTypeCount:
                    DLog("resultTypeCount")
                case .resultTypeObjectIDs:
                    DLog("resultTypeObjectIDs")
                case .resultTypeStatusOnly:
                    DLog("resultTypeStatusOnly")
                }
                if let objectIDArray = result?.result as? [NSManagedObjectID] {
                    let changes = [NSDeletedObjectsKey : objectIDArray]
                    NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: changes, into: [unwrappedContext])
                }
                try context?.save()
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            DLog("Error removing : \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine, but the result of the batch delete is always `.resultTypeStatusOnly`

The documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/CoreData_Batch_Guide/BatchDeletes/BatchDeletes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016086-CH3-SW2 says under the title *Updating Your Application After Execution* that

> it is important that you notify the application that the objects in
>   memory are stale and need to be refreshed.

And to do that the result type has to be `.resultTypeObjectIDs`, to be able to trigger the `NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: changes, into: [unwrappedContext])` part. It's just not clear how you get that.

How does one set the type of the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `resultType` property on the `batchDeleteRequest`. So, also from https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/CoreData_Batch_Guide/BatchDeletes/BatchDeletes.html :

> When the executeRequest completes successfully, a response is received. That response can take one of two forms. The form of the response is deteremined by setting the resultType property on the NSBatchDeleteRequest. The default value is NSStatusOnlyResultType, which returns nothing. 
>   The other option is NSBatchDeleteObjectIDsResultType, which returns an array of NSManagedObjectID instances indicating which entities were deleted during the execution.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: The correct syntax is: `batchDeleteRequest.resultType = .resultTypeObjectIDs`

Comment: Looks like it changed, in Swift 5.6 it is .managedObjectIDResultType